# What does the Haskell function forall do and where is it defined?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading [A Little Lens Starter Tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) and they use a seemingly magical function `forall` like this:

```
>>> forall $ \tuple -> view _1 tuple == fst tuple
True
```

What exactly does this function do and more importantly what package is it from. I can't find it using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), etc.

Comment: It's not a real function, but keep in mind that it is possible to get similar behaviour (perhaps with a little more work) using QuickCheck, which generates hundreds or thousands of test cases for you on the fly.

Comment: That always struck me as a confusing aspect of that tutorial, especially since it doesn't explain that `forall` doesn't exist in that form and it doesn't mention QuickCheck.

Comment: That's very confusing then.  Why not just write `view _1 = fst`?

Comment: @TomEllis Because I didn't want to talk about what equality means, though just dodging the question entirely has clearly caused more confusion.

Comment: @DavidYoung I've added a more direct explanation and a reference to QuickCheck now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haha, embarrassed author here.

I invented `forall` to mime `quickCheck` and make intuitive sense, but not to be executable. In my defense, I took inspiration from the Little Schemer which happily introduces syntax and semantics far before they're executable in order to build intuition by practice.

Except, of course, my `forall` is not actually executable at all and it has lead to a lot of confusion.

So, my suggestion to anyone curious is to investigate `quickcheck` as a stand-in for `forall`. My suggestion to myself, [now carried out](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial#-sidenote--what-is-that-forall-thing--), is to edit the tutorial to note my artistic license there.

Sorry about any trouble.

Answer (score 4):

That's not actually executable code.  See this answer: https://twitter.com/vh4x0r/status/429256064245067777